# How to pass a parameter from one .jsp page to another using JSF

Tags: jsp, jsf, parameter-passing

I'm creating a small project which consists in creating a small e-shop using JSF 2.1.
The problem I am encountering is the following:
I want to display "Hi, customerName" where customerName is the name of the customer who logged in, same with the Admin.
For example an admin called "Trevor" logs in, and the app redirects you to a page where it says "Hi, Trevor".

It all goes fine the first time I do that, using:

```
<h:outputFormat value="Welcome, {0}.">
    <f:param value="#{adminController.admin.name}" />
 </h:outputFormat>
```

But then if I perform another operation, like creating and persisting a Product, if at the end I make the user click a button to return to loggedAdminHomePage.jsp, it simply displays "Welcolme, null".
How can I display the Admin/User name every time he performs an operation and returns to his homepage?

Comment: As you're using the deprecated JSP view technology, may we assume that you're using JSF 1.x? Regardless, please always mention the JSF impl/version in every question about JSF. As to the problem, how exactly are you logging in the user? Using a homegrown login mechanism which doesn't remember the user in current HTTP session? That would explain everything.

Comment: I' m using JSF 2.1. And yes, the login mechanism simply retrieves the user with a certain email, and checks if the password is correct. So, the user is put into a variable into userController. It lets me access this the first time, but performing another operation nullifies the reference.

Comment: Why don't you just remember the login in current HTTP session? Just make userController a session scoped bean.

Comment: But then how can I move through my pages? Just using a "classic" <a href etc.../> doesn't work anymore. I would like to use the commandLink, but I don't know how to redirect to other jsp pages rather than to something like [...]#{adminController.login} ??

Comment: Hm? That problem is caused elsewhere.

Comment: I'm using a SessionScoped bean, but the page just doesn't load.